# Create Read-Only MongoDB container read data of the existing MongoDB container

Tags: mongodb, docker, readonly

I have running MongoDB as Docker container. Now I want to create one more MongoDB container but read-only and read data from the existing one.

What should I do? I don't use Docker Swarm mode!

I want to have 2 MongoDB container run, the existing is keep running, the new one is read-only and read data from the existing container.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Do you want to create a replica set where the MongoDB process in the new container is in read-only SECONDARY state?

Comment: Yes, what should I do to create it?